# IMPORTRANGE sum column with condition

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

=SUM(IMPORTRANGE("1kWMBhk0T423p411K5_5sKOMQFdAsEDapdasYyr9gZj8","Oct!N2:N") "SELECT Col16, where Col16 contains 'Paid' )")

I need to calculate only the total of paid invoices

Does somebody had a similar situation?

Answer (score 0):

The formula is using incorrect syntax, and there are semantic issues as well. You are only importing one column. That column cannot simultaneously contain 'Paid' and a number in the same row.

Use this pattern:

```
=query( 
  importrange("1kWMBhk0T423p411K5_5sKOMQFdAsEDapdasYyr9gZj8", "Oct!A2:Z"), 
  "select sum(Col9) where Col14 contains 'Paid' label sum(Col9) '' ", 
  0 
)
```

Replace `Col9` with a reference to the column you want to sum, and `Col14` with a reference to the column that contains `Paid` flags.

Comment: This was so much helpful. thank you!

Comment: @user321359 comments are not for thank you's.  If you feel the answer was useful to you, consider [upvoting and/or accepting it](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).